# Value is not binding in kendoui dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendoui dropdownlist. I am loading the values in the dropdownlist dynamically.
I have written the code like

```
   $("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
       dataSource:
        {
            transport: {
                read:
                 {
                  url: "/Projects/Dropdown",
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "json"
                 }
           },
        },
        dataTextField: "type",
        dataValueField: "type",
        value: "Type2",
      });
```

And in the controller i have defined like:

```
    public ActionResult Dropdown(int projectid, int controlid)
    {
       var values = Context.controloptions.Where(i => i.id== id).Select(i => new {              
        type = i.value
       }).ToArray();

       return Json(values, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The values will contains an array:
     `[{type="Type1"},{type="Type2"}]`. How can i bind the value of "Type2" by giving the value.
  I am adding the screen shot of the value that are coming.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either define the `DropDownList` as:

```
$("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource   : {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url     : "/Projects/Dropdown",
                type    : "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    },
    value: "Type2"
});
```

or return the data as `[{"type":"Type1"},{"type":"Type2"}]` and define the `DropDownList` as:

```
$("#dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource   : {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url     : "/Projects/Dropdown",
                type    : "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    },
    dataTextField: "type",
    dataValueField: "type",
    value        : "Type2"
});
```

Comment: I have tried the second procedure. But the Type2 is not binding. Only the first value is selecting

Comment: Did you verify that `url : "/Projects/Dropdown"` is returning `[{"type":"Type1"},{"type":"Type2"}]`? (Try opening the url in a browser).

Comment: I have attached the image of the records that are coming

Comment: Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/wgREh/ The difference is that in Fiddle I cannot setup an external data source and set it as a vector but you will see that the format is the same.